# Do I publish tsconfig.json to NPM or not?

Tags: typescript, npm

TSC has recently started generation `tsconfig.tsbuildinfo` files. I'm now adding those to `.npmignore` to prevent me from publishing them to NPM, because they're artifacts to keep track of local builds.

This got me to thinking, should I be stripping `tsconfig.json` from the NPM published package as well?

It seems to me that the file is only used as instructions to the compiler, and so could safely be stripped. However, I also know that when the TypeScript compiler uses files, it sometimes uses the tsconfig from the target project as well (for example, when using project references).

I can't oversee the result of this move--will downstream builds break under some esoteric conditions if I strip `tsconfig.json` from my NPM packages?

Comment: What made you publish it in the first place?

Comment: Ignorance. Didn't know that I was

Comment: As you've said `tsconfig.json` is only relevant when developing and compiling the package, once published it is no longer relevant and you can safely exclude it from the shipped content. I personally use package.json's `"files":` field rather than `.npmignore` but that's a matter of taste